# How do I get the number of connected clients from Alfred?

Tags: fluid-framework

I found that Alfred [knows](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/df9fa1fe7a7bcc9019689a48dbee81ff431ef004/server/routerlicious/packages/services/src/redisClientManager.ts#L47) all connected clients for a given (tenant, document) pair. However, I haven't found any HTTP or WebSocket APIs to get to this information. Did I miss something?
Why do I need this?
I'm building a bot (a server-side client to fluid) that will be responsible for converting file representation to fluid and vice versa. My bot needs to know when the last client is gone so that it can convert the fluid ops back into a (legacy) file.

Answer (score 0):

We don't provide a service side API to fetch list of connected clients. However, we maintain the list of all writer clients in our [quorum](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/main/server/routerlicious/packages/protocol-base/src/quorum.ts#L217). Using this, you can always track list of writers connected to the session.

Note that for your scenario, this will require your bot to be already running so that it can track when everyone leaves the session. If you only want to spawn the bot only when every client leaves, you can track the [noClient](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/main/common/lib/protocol-definitions/src/protocol.ts#L41) op. We send this op when everyone leaves the session.